# Eclipse CDT formatting - wrap after operator

Tags: eclipse, formatting, code-formatting

I would like to know how to achieve this in EclipseCDT formater:

Input:

```
if ((example1 + example1 < example2) || (example3 + example4 < example5) || (example1 + example1 < example2))
{
     printf("sth");
}
```

Expected:

```
if ((example1 + example1 < example2) || (example3 + example4 < example5) ||
    (example1 + example1 < example2)) 
{
   printf("sth");
}
```

or

```
if ((example1 + example1 < example2) || 
    (example3 + example4 < example5) ||
    (example1 + example1 < example2)) 
{
   printf("sth");
}
```

Eclipse gives me this(wrap before operator):

```
if ((example1 + example1 < example2)
   || (example3 + example4 < example5)
   || (example1 + example1 < example2))
{
    printf("sth");
}
```

There is another option, clang-formatter but I cannot use it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available in other versions of Eclipse (for instance the standard Java one), but not in Eclipse CDT.

A request was opened in [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360107), you should probably upvote it if you are interested in having this feature added to the CDT product.